Phase-shift Profilometry Camera-Projector pixel correspondence
For structured light active illumination techniques like Phase-shift Profilometry (Fringe Pattern Projection), after phase unwrapping has been completed (usually Temporal Phase Unwrapping as Spatial Phase Unwrapping is prone to noise and surface discontinuities) to obtain an absolute/continunous/unwrapped phase map, how can we establish a pixel-to-pixel correspondence between each camera pixel to its corresponding projector pixel(s)?
I am unable to find any resource on it?
If this is not the correct stack, which would be the most appropriate stack for this question?
